# Left click not working on notifyicon with contextmenustrip

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, notifyicon, contextmenustrip

I have a tray application and I would like to open the ContextMenuStrip if I click on the tray logo. This is my code:

```
    private void notifyIcon1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            timeBroMenu.Show(Cursor.Position);
        }
    }
```

Double click is working easily.

```
   private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        timeBroMenu.Show(Cursor.Position);
    }
```

Is there any way to make the left click work?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info about how the NotifyIcon and the ContextMenuStrip is initialized?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to handle the Click event if you have assigned the NotifyIcon's ContextMenuStrip Property.

Comment: I do not have a problem with the assigning of ContextMenuStrip to notifyicon. As described a double click ist working. I just cant get the simple left click to open the menu.